# How can I correctly format currency using jquery?

Tags: jquery, currency, formatter

I do not need a mask, but I need something that will format currency(in all browsers) and not allow for any letters or special char's to be typed.  Thanks for the help

Example:

Valid: $50.00
       $1,000.53

Not Valid: $w45.00
           $34.3r6

Comment: Can you explain why the other ones didnt fit your standards?

Comment: StackOverflow is my search engine for questions like this.  The community feedback here allows a much quicker and more accurate picture of what tools and practices are valued.  I say, keep these types of questions coming.

Comment: Got here from Google.

Comment: This question is the top Google search result for "jquery format currency"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-string)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**JQUERY FORMATCURRENCY PLUGIN** 
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

Comment: Too bad that isn't compatible with the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: this one works pretty well as of jquery 2.0 http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/

Answer (score 107):

Another option (If you are using ASP.Net razor view) is, On your view you can do

```
<div>@String.Format("{0:C}", Model.total)</div>
```

This would format it correctly. note (item.total is double/decimal)

if in jQuery you can also use Regex

```
$(".totalSum").text('$' + parseFloat(total, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
```

Comment: I didn’t vote this down, but I can’t find `@String.Format` in any HTML or jQuery reference. My guess is it has something to do with server-side HTML generated by ASP.NET. Did the original question reference that?

Comment: For anyone wondering in the future, @String.Format is the razor engine for ASP.NET || MVC

Comment: I like the regex. Why .toString() at the end? .replace returns a string.

Comment: I didn't downvote this either, but it deserves it for giving an MVC Razor solution to a question that didn't mention Razor, MVC, or even ASP.NET, and the answer didn't even state that here's a solution for MVC Razor.

Comment: This is a great answer, but how do I need to change the regex in order to get a number without any decimal places and without the dollar symbol?  eg I'd like 16000000 to be displayed as 16,000,000

Comment: Never mind, I've answered my own question:
$(".totalSum").text('$' + parseFloat(value, 10).toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(?:[0-9]{3})+\b)/gm, "$1,").toString());

Comment: What about if I want to replace the decimal separator for ',' and the others for '.'?

Comment: After searching everywhere with suggestion of plugins and so on, this one worked perfectly!

Answer (score 40):

Expanding upon Melu's answer you can do this to functionalize the code and handle negative amounts.

Sample Output:
$5.23
-$5.23

```
function formatCurrency(total) {
    var neg = false;
    if(total < 0) {
        neg = true;
        total = Math.abs(total);
    }
    return (neg ? "-$" : '$') + parseFloat(total, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString();
}
```

Answer (score 22):

As a corollary to why the jQuery FormatCurrency plugin is a good answer, I'd like to rebut your comment:

*1. code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency - Does not filter out all letter's. You can type a single letter and it will not remove it.*

Yes, formatCurrency() by itself does not filter out letters:

```
// only formats currency
$(selector).formatCurrency();
```

But toNumber(), included in the formatCurrency plugin, does.

You thus want to do:

```
// removes invalid characters, then formats currency
$(selector).toNumber().formatCurrency();
```

Answer (score 16):

Use [jquery.inputmask 3.x](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).
See demos [here](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/)

Include files:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.inputmask.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.inputmask.numeric.extensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And code as

```
$(selector).inputmask('decimal',
  { 'alias': 'numeric',
    'groupSeparator': '.',
    'autoGroup': true,
    'digits': 2,
    'radixPoint': ",",
    'digitsOptional': false,
    'allowMinus': false,
    'prefix': '$ ',
    'placeholder': '0'
  }
);
```

Highlights:

- easy to use
- optional parts anywere in the mask
- possibility to define aliases which hide complexity
- date / datetime masks
- numeric masks
- lots of callbacks
- non-greedy masks
- many features can be enabled/disabled/configured by options
- supports readonly/disabled/dir="rtl" attributes
- support data-inputmask attribute(s)
- multi-mask support
- regex-mask support
- dynamic-mask support
- preprocessing-mask support
- value formatting / validating without input element

Comment: after downloading the ZIP (from the web) i found that the *.js file inside the ZIP is having a different file naming convention. I a bit confused....

Comment: @gumuruh Look into dist/ folder of the ZIP file. The ZIPs into root of extracted folder are of package and does not for use. Attention to the extensions. Load only what you should need.

Comment: @FernandoKosh @drew010 Is it possible to use this for multiple elements on a page? With for example: 
`$('.price-format').inputmaks()` 
or 
`$('.price-format').each(function() { $(this).inputmask() })`

Comment: @remkovdm It's been a while since I've implemented it now, but yes I believe that was fine. The docs and examples show $(selector) which means it can be a CSS selector like any other jQuery one. So `$('.price-format').inputmask('decimal',
  { ... });` *should* work.

Answer (score 10):

I used to use the jquery format currency plugin, but it has been very buggy recently. I only need formatting for USD/CAD, so I wrote my own automatic formatting.

```
$(".currencyMask").change(function () {
            if (!$.isNumeric($(this).val()))
                $(this).val('0').trigger('change');

            $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val(), 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
        });
```

Simply set the class of whatever input should be formatted as currency `<input type="text" class="currencyMask" />` and it will format it perfectly in any browser.

Answer (score 4):

Try regexp currency with jQuery **(no plugin)**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').click(function() {
    TESTCURRENCY = $('#value').val().toString().match(/(?=[\s\d])(?:\s\.|\d+(?:[.]\d+)*)/gmi);
    if (TESTCURRENCY.length <= 1) {
      $('#valueshow').val(
        parseFloat(TESTCURRENCY.toString().match(/^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/))
      );
    } else {
      $('#valueshow').val('Invalid a value!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="12345.67890" id="value">
<input type="button" id="test" value="CLICK">
<input type="text" value="" id="valueshow">
```

Edit: New check a value to valid/invalid

Comment: What the problem to downvote? This question (Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late is thanks)

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript already has it.

```
var cur = function (amt) {
    return Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: "currency", currency: "USD" }).format(amt);
};
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Most of answers had offered all kind of crap like .NET based solutions.

“Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.” – Leonardo da Vinci

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
@{
    CultureInfo newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Model.culture);
var ri = new RegionInfo(@newCulture.LCID);
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).find("#labGrandTotal").text(Intl.NumberFormat('@Model.culture', { style: 'currency', currency: '@ri.ISOCurrencySymbol'}).format(num));
```

Where Model.culture is for example "en-GB"