# Jquery in a Ember js Application on ie8/ie7 not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, view, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm have a problem with this browsers,  the application works correctly on a another browsers, but have a problem in internet explorer 8 and 7

> SCRIPT438: Object does not support this property or method
>   jquery.js?body=1, linha 612 Caractere 4

```
globalEval: function( data ) {
if ( data && rnotwhite.test( data ) ) {
    // We use execScript on Internet Explorer
    // We use an anonymous function so that context is window
    // rather than jQuery in Firefox
    ( window.execScript || function( data ) {
        window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );
    } )( data );
}
},
```

my application use Rails 3.2.13

A example of my views

```
Webapp.MenuView = Ember.View.extend
 templateName: 'menu'
 classNames: ['invisible']
 # tagName: 'form'

 toggleMenu: ->
  if lefty = $("#menu_roll")
   lefty.show().animate
    display: "block"
    left: (if parseInt(lefty.css("left"), 10) is 0 then -lefty.outerWidth() else 0)
    right: (if parseInt(lefty.css("right"), 10) is 0 then lefty.outerWidth() else 0)

 voltarMap: ->
  console.log "voltar para o mapa"
  Webapp.addr.resetOpcionais() if Webapp.addr
  @get("controller").transitionToRoute "MapEmEspera"

 voltar: ->
  if window.location.hash is "#/forgot_password" or window.location.hash is    "#/cadastrar"
  window.location = window.location.origin + "/welcome"
else
  @get("controller").transitionToRoute "MapEmEspera"

terms: ->
 window.open(window.location.origin + "/terms")
 # window.location = window.location + "/terms"

display: (c) ->
 @toggleMenu()
 @get("controller").transitionToRoute c

logout : ->
 Webapp.alert("Tem certeza que deseja sair da WayTaxi?", ->
    Webapp.shutdown()
  , ->
    $('#alert').hide()
  )
```

Comment: Did you try searching for that error? Do these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975922/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-ie or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952906/script438-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-formatcurrency

Comment: yes, I've seen topics but were not useful, in another view the error occurs when inside in the didInsertElement